# How can I pass a parameter to a Bootstrap UI modal function to set a template?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, callback, bootstrap-modal, angular-template

I'm using Angular with Bootstrap UI and am trying to open a modal using a template that depends on if/else logic.  When I pass the function to open the modal a parameter for the 'template' property, it doesn't use the argument passed to the function callback.  I get this error in the console: 
*"One of template or templateUrl options is required"*
If I hard code the file path, the modal opens up just fine. It's only when I pass in a parameter that I get this error.

```
angular.module('butterflyappApp').controller('YelpapiCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyYelpAPI', 'googlemapsservice', 'CheckGeo',
  '$uibModal',
  function($scope, MyYelpAPI, googlemapsservice, CheckGeo, $uibModal) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.open = function(template) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: template,
        controller: 'ModalCtrl as vm'
      });
    };

    $scope.checkGeoClick = function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          CheckGeo.checkerYelp(latChecker, longChecker);
          $scope.testStuff = CheckGeo.test();
          if (pos.lat.toFixed(3) === $scope.testStuff.newLatChecker && pos.long.toFixed(3) === $scope.testStuff
            .newLongChecker) {
            console.log('you win');
            vm.open(winningMoal);
          } else {
            console.log('/views/modal-view-winning.html');
            vm.open('/views/modalview.html');
          }
        });
      };
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.open(winningMoal);
```

Are you sure you are using the correct variable name? I don't see a variable named `winningMoal` anywhere in the code